# Prevent duplicate option on two checkboxes with same options

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I have 2 select box where I'm trying to avoid duplicated values (options) in those select box's.
they all start with the same options list but after selecting option in `selectA` this option wont bee seen in `selectB` and vice versa.
It should work if you select on `selectA-selectB-selectA`... etc.
Every time one of the select box should be with **n-1** options.

I did the next this.. it works but in mobile device the `.hide()` it's not working!

```
   $('#selectA').bind('change', function () {
            $("#selectB option").show();
            $("#selectB option[value='" + $(this + 'option:selected').attr('value') + "']").hide();
        });
    $('#selectB').bind('change', function () {
        $("#selectA option").show();
        alert($(this).find('option:selected').attr('value'));
        $("#selectA option[value='" + $(this).find('option:selected').attr('value') + "']").hide();
    });
}
```

Tried with class :  `.hide()`

```
.hide {display: none;}



  $('#selectA').bind('change', function () {
            $("#selectB option").removeClass('hide');
            $("#selectB option[value='" + $(this + 'option:selected').attr('value') + "']").addClass('hide');
        });

        $('#selectB').bind('change', function () {
            $("#selectA option").removeClass('hide');
            $("#selectA option[value='" + $(this).find('option:selected').attr('value') + "']").addClass('hide');
        });
    }
```

also dont work.

tried this:

```
    $('#selectA').on('change', function() {
        $('option:not(:selected)', this).clone().appendTo($('#selectB').empty());
    });

$('#selectB').on('change', function() {
        $('option:not(:selected)', this).clone().appendTo($('#selectA').empty());
    });
```

but the problem here is if we start with 5 options for example then after selecting option in `selectA` I'll get **n-1** in `selectB`,after selecting option in
`selectB` I'll get **n-2** in `selectA` and so on... in the end you get empty list.

any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: `display: none` doesnt work for selectmenu on mobiles. Disable selected option instead.

Comment: I cant set `.enable()\.disable()`. something like this?  `$("#selectB option").enable();     $("#selectB option[value='" + $(this + 'option:selected').attr('value') + "']").disable();` ?

Comment: For example `$("#select option:selected").prop("disabled", true);` demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/qMxy3/

Comment: It works, but I still trying some how to hide\remove it so it wont bee even disabled in the list. ofcourse I cant remove it because it will destroy my original list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GCFLG/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#selectA').on('change', function() { UpdateDropdown($(this), $('#selectB')); })
    $('#selectB').on('change', function() { UpdateDropdown($(this), $('#selectA')); })

    function UpdateDropdown($source, $target) {
        var $sourceitems = $('option:not(:selected)', $source).clone();
        var sourcevalues = $.map($sourceitems, function(option) { return option.value; });
        var $targetitem = $target.find(':selected');

        if ($.inArray($targetitem.val(), sourcevalues) == -1) {
           $sourceitems = $.merge($sourceitems, $targetitem);
        }

        $sourceitems.appendTo($target.empty());
    }
});
```

If keeping sort order is important [fiddle with sort](http://jsfiddle.net/GCFLG/1/)

Comment: I like the idea, but after some clicks, the dropdownlist options are all shuffled around.

Comment: OP didn't mention order as part of the specs although it does seem convenient. Adding a data-attribute to sort on would be simple enough.

Comment: Looks like a great solution, the sorted version is nice. I wonder is it can be implemented in pure javaScript?